# Harvard Referencing for Webinars

Tags: citation-style, audio-video-recording

I want to cite a webinar in the Harvard citation style.

I have found many websites talk about website referencing but could not find anything about webinars!

How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By googling your title, I found this style valid for online videos, webinars, etc.:

> Author/Speaker (Year) Title of communication [Medium]. Available at: URL (Accessed:
>   date).

The source I used was [London Metropolitan University Library Services' Harvard Referencing Guide](https://student.londonmet.ac.uk/media/london-metropolitan-university/london-met-documents/professional-service-departments/library-services/referencing/HarvardReferencingGuideFull2016-05.pdf), but their stance seems to be corroborated by [other](https://www.dkit.ie/system/files/dkit_guide_to_harvard_referencing_0.pdf) referencing guides.

Adapted reference list example:

> Stepp, K. (2013) HR & the workplace of the future [Webinar]. Available at:
>   http://www.slideshare.net/thetalentproject/hr-the-workplace-of-the-future (Accessed: 18
>   December 2013).

Note that there actually is no definitive Harvard referencing guide, so the journal you submit to (or university for a thesis) could have slightly different requirements. Nevertheless, the above citation is clear enough, and should be acceptable in most places.